# Shell command to iterate through every line of a text file

Tags: shell

I'm trying to run ack in my current directory with the keyword to be each line of a text file, and I tried the following command on the command line:

```
cat ~/temp/imageFileNames.txt | while read line; do ack "$line"; done
```

However, no output was produced at all, even though each line individually produces output if I run ack on it manually. 
What's the problem with this command?

Comment: Why run `ack` line-by-line, instead of running it directly on the file: `ack "$line" ~/temp/imageFileNames.txt`?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, I didn't know ack can take in a text file and iterate through each line and run ack on every single line. However I tried it but somehow it prints out the whole file on the screen. Does the "$line" automatically get each line in the file?

Comment: I'm actually not too familiar with `[ack](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ack)`, just Linux ;). Since chat is better suited for this back-and-forth, I'll update this question with the answer, and if you have a different problem, just ask again :)

Comment: Is it that ack or [this ack](http://man.cx/ack)?

Answer (score 1):

`ack` works on whole files, line-by-line. For this, just do:

```
ack "$line" ~/temp/imageFileNames.txt
```

And it should print out all lines that contain whatever you put for "$line". Check the docs for a better usage description than I can give: http://linux.die.net/man/1/ack

Comment: OK I see what you mean... Sorry to confuse you but this is not what I meant. Basically I need to run ack on all subdirectories in the current directory, normally I do this with ack "keyword". However, I need to run this command many times because I need to search for different keywords in the whole workspace. I'm not trying to search for a single keyword in one file. Rather, all these keywords are stored in one text file, and I need to look up each keyword in all subdirectories of my current directory

Comment: I'd use `grep -r` (recursive search): http://blamcast.net/articles/recursive-grep-find-strings-files. For questions like this, I'd go check http://superuser.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/. SO is more for writing programs, those guys know bash much better.